# How to update selected value in database via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically generated select where customer can choose supplier ($sid) for product ($pid):

```
<select name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" onchange="func(this.value)">
    <?php foreach...{ ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
        <?php echo $value; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And ajax call which has to assign the chosen value to the product:

```
<script>
    function func(selectedValue){
        var pid = $('name').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {sid : selectedValue, pid : pid},
            success: function() {
                alert("Ok");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And update.php

```
<?php
    $pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];
    $val = $_REQUEST['sid'];
    $sid = json_encode($val);
    $query = "UPDATE `orders` SET sid = '$sid' WHERE pid = '$pid'";
    try {    
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
    $STH=$DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $DBH=null;
    ?>
```

But the information does not update. Where is my mistake?

Comment: show your `update.php` file.

Comment: Did you get the `Ok` alert?

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: i updated my question and included update.php there. And i didn't get any alert and no errors...

Comment: what is this: $('name').val()? and what is the output of $pid and $val and $sid in the php file?

Comment: Sorry, the alert appears, but database record does not update.

Comment: $('name').val is the name of "select", which is product id

Comment: Try to put `alert(selectedValue);` and `alert(pid)` after `var pid = $('name').val();`, do you get the correct `selectedValue` and `pid`?

Comment: I get 'undefined' for alert(pid)

Comment: do i get "option name" right? i guess there's a syntax error. How can i get the $pid with jquery?

Comment: Is `$pid` the same for all of the options?

Comment: yes, inside a select $pid is the same

Comment: Please check my answer below, I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

var pid = $('name').val(); with var pid = selectedValue;

Comment: But pid is not for supplier, it's for product id which is select and option name' value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];
    //$val = $_REQUEST['sid']; // you may write wrong here
    //$sid = json_encode($val);
    $sid= $_REQUEST['sid'];
    $query = "UPDATE `orders` SET sid = '$sid' WHERE pid = '$pid'";
    try {    
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
    $STH=$DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $DBH=null;
    ?>
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function func(selectedValue){
        var pid = $('#product option:selected').attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {sid : selectedValue, pid : pid},
            success: function() {
                alert("Ok");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<select id="product" name="<?php echo $pid; ?>"  onchange="func(this.value)">
    <?php foreach...{ ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
        <?php echo $value; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I cannot get the pid value from the "option name". I tested the php with defined values, and it works fine.. I guess the problem is in syntax

Comment: please say difference between pid & sid

Comment: pid is for product id and sid is for supplier id. i need to assign chosen sid to the product with the pid

Comment: is pid changable? when the sid is changed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't get the correct `pid` because of this wrong jquery selector

```
$('name').val()
```

You need to add `id` attribute to `<select>` tag, let's say it's `product`

```
<select id="product" name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" onchange="func(this.value)">
    <?php foreach...{ ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
        <?php echo $value; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Since `$pid` is always the same, you can get it by using this selector

```
$('#product').attr('name')
```

and set `pid` to the above as follows

```
<script>
    function func(selectedValue){
        var pid = $('#product').attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {sid : selectedValue, pid : pid},
            success: function() {
                alert("Ok");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace :

```
 var pid = $('name').val();
```

with this:

```
var pid = $(this).attr('name');
```

The above code will fetch the value of 'name'

The below code will fetch sid

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing the important part putting a name to the select not the value.
2. Instead use id to call your function in your script.

```html
<select name="supplier" id="getValue">
    <?php foreach...{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
        <?php echo $value; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

On your javascript put this code:
note that the line var formVals = $('form').serialize();  will get all the inputs that your form will pass.

```js
$('#getValue').on('change', function() {
    var formVals = $('form').serialize(); 
     $.ajax({
          url: "update.php",
          type: 'POST',
          async : false,
          data: formVals,
          success: function(data) {

                alert("Ok");
                location.reload();   
          }


        });

    
    
});
```

and lastly change $_REQUEST to $_POST['supplier'];

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML like this: (change to onchange="func(this)")

```
<select name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" onchange="func(this)">
<?php foreach...{ ?>
<option name="<?php echo $pid; ?>" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
    <?php echo $value; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And in the code you call ajax:

```
<script>
function func(element){
    var selectedValue = $(element).val();
    var pid = $(element).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {sid : selectedValue, pid : pid},
        success: function() {
            alert("Ok");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And in the update.php file:

```
<?php
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$val = $_POST['sid'];
$sid = json_encode($val);//I don't know why you have this line, this line should be removed
$query = "UPDATE `orders` SET sid = '$sid' WHERE pid = '$pid'";
try {    
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$STH=$DBH->prepare($query);
$STH->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$DBH=null;
?>
```